# Count duplicates in ArcGIS, ArcMap 10.4

Tags: arcgis-desktop, topology, overlapping-features, arcgis-10.4, duplication

How can I find how many duplicates I have in my dataset (areas, lines, points) using ArcMap?

With topology I can find overlapping objects, but I want to find duplicates.

Are there any tools from toolbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the help docs for: [Finding duplicate geometry](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/data-reviewer/finding-duplicate-geometry.htm) for ArcMap 10.4:

> 1. Start ArcMap.
> 2. On the main menu, click **Customize** > **Toolbars** > **Data Reviewer**.
> 3. Click the **Select Data** Check drop-down arrow on the **Data Reviewer** toolbar, click the plus sign (+) next to **Duplicate Geometry Checks**, then click **Duplicate Geometry Check**.
>
>    The **Duplicate Geometry Check** Properties dialog box appears.

You can then set the feature class, check for identical matches in attributes etc.

Comment: What should I do when I don't have "data reviewer"?

Comment: @GosiaS. - This is assuming you have the **Data Reviewer license**, which if you do then you may need to install it: [Installing ArcGIS Data Reviewer for Desktop](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/install/data-reviewer/installing-arcgis-data-reviewer-for-desktop.htm). Saying that, I think Aaron's answer is correct as you mentioned finding duplicates in your dataset, not necessarily in the geometry...

Comment: Ok, I install it. What should I do now, when my data reveiwer toolbar is not active? I can't click on any button?

Comment: @GosiaS. - Does Aaron's answer solve your problem?

Comment: I don't think that "Find Identical" tool is working right on my dataset, i want to use Data Reviewer but i don/t know how to activate this buttons

Comment: @GosiaS. - I am not an ArcGIS user so can't comment much apart from suggesting to restart ArcGIS if you haven't already done so. Otherwise, you may need to ask a [new question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) about why the Data Reviewer toolbar is not active.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Find Identical (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000054000000) tool to find duplicate features or records.

> Reports any records in a feature class or table that have identical
>   values in a list of fields, and generates a table listing these
>   identical records. If the field Shape is selected, feature geometries
>   are compared.
>
> The Delete Identical tool can be used to find and delete identical
>   records.